# inconvertible types, can not cast 'android.view.ActionProvider' to 'android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider'

Tags: android

Trying the follwing:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html#setShareIntent(android.content.Intent)

Getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fix is in using `android.widget`'s ShareActionProvider in declartion instead of `android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider`'s

declare like this:

```
private android.widget.ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
```

and then in onCreateOptionsMenu() do this:

```
mShareActionProvider = (android.widget.ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `ShareActionProvider` from `package android.widget;` check your import statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get this to work pre API 14, you also need to use a MenuItemCompat that will allow you to get the v7 share action provider.  So change:

```
shareActionProvider2 = (android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider(item);
```

to

```
shareActionProvider2 = (android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
```

And please note you cannot create an instance of [MenuItemCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat) - for example, you can NOT simply change MenuItem item to MenuItemCompat.  MenuItemCompat just provides static methods that can be used on a MenuItem.